# How to optimize postgresql using functions or procedure

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

How to optimize postgreql when The report is extremely slow. Im looking for a way to reduce subqueries. I have multiple of these subqueries doing the same calculation but with different parameter intervals. e.g interval 'day 271', interval 'day 365'. Each cal for each interval is done in a separate subquery currently, would like to implement this another way and avoid subqueries, since i realized they making the report generation really slow.

```
SELECT

    merchandiseCode,
    merchandiseDescription,
    merchandiseCategory_ID,
    merchandiseCategory,
    Case OnHand WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE CurrentCost*OnHand END AS CurrentCost, 
    CASE WHEN qty5>0 OR qty4>0 OR qty3>0 OR qty2>0 THEN stock1 ELSE CASE WHEN 
     qty1 >0 THEN qty1 ELSE 0 END END as qty1,
    CASE WHEN qty5>0 OR qty4>0 OR qty3>0 THEN stock2 ELSE CASE WHEN qty2>0 
    THEN qty2 ELSE 0 END END as qty2,
    CASE WHEN qty5>0 OR qty4>0 THEN stock3 ELSE CASE WHEN qty3 >0 THEN qty3 
     ELSE 0 END END AS qty3,  
    CASE WHEN qty5>0 THEN Stock4 ELSE  CASE WHEN qty4> 0 THEN qty4 ELSE 0 END 
    END AS qty4,
    CASE WHEN qty5>0 THEN qty5 ELSE 0 END As qty5,
    stock1,
    stock2,
    stock3,
    stock4,
    OnHand,

    CASE WHEN qty5>0 OR qty4>0 OR qty3>0 OR qty2>0 THEN round(stock1* 
    (cost1),2) ELSE CASE WHEN qty1 >0 THEN round(qty1*(cost1),2) ELSE 0 END 
   END as value1,

    CASE WHEN qty5>0 OR qty4>0 OR qty3>0 THEN round(stock2*(cost2),2) ELSE 
   CASE WHEN qty2>0 THEN round(qty2*(cost2),2) ELSE 0 END END as value2,

    CASE WHEN qty5>0 OR qty4>0 THEN round(Stock3*(Cost3),2) ELSE CASE WHEN 
    qty3 >0 THEN round(qty3*(cost3),2) ELSE 0 END END as value3,

    CASE WHEN qty5>0 THEN round(Stock4*(Cost4),2) ELSE CASE WHEN qty4>0 THEN 
    round(qty4*(Cost4),2) ELSE 0 END END as value4,

    CASE WHEN qty5>0 THEN round(qty5*(cost4),2) ELSE 0 END as value5

    from (
    SELECT 

    prod.value as merchandiseCode,
    prod.description as merchandiseDescription,
    prod.merchandiseCategory_ID as merchandiseCategory_ID,
    prodcat.name AS merchandiseCategory,

    (SELECT COALESCE((cos.NewCostPrice),0) 
    FROM  M_CostM cos  WHERE cos.Created = (SELECT MAX(c.Created)
    FROM M_CostM c 
    LEFT JOIN M_CostElement ce on ce.M_CostElement_UU='bf6ee9b8-4600-480b- 
     b415-f94c698b0648'
    WHERE
    prod.M_Product_ID = c.M_Product_ID AND prod.ProductType !='A'
    AND c.created <= ('2020-02-17'::date)
    AND c.Customer_ID =1000008  AND c.C_AcctSchema_ID = 1000009
    AND c.M_CostElement_ID=ce.M_CostElement_ID
    AND c.rg_ID  = CASE WHEN c.AD_Org_ID =0 Then c.AD_Org_ID ELSE  1000002  
    END 
    )) as CurrentCost,

    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.movementqty),0) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementdate > (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 90') 
    AND t.movementdate <('2020-02-17'::date)
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+')) AS stock1,  ----stock 
    exist from previous brackets

    (SELECT (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449  
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+') 
    AND t.movementdate<('2020-02-17'::date)
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044 ) + 
    (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008  
    AND t.movementtype IN('I-','C-','M-','P-','V-','W-') 
    AND t.movementdate<('2020-02-17'::date) 
    AND t.rg_ID  = 1000044)) AS qty1,

    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.movementqty),0) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementdate > (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 180') 
    AND t.movementdate <=  (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 91')
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+')) AS stock2,  ----stock 
    exist from previous brackets

    (SELECT (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449  
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+') 
    AND t.movementdate<(('2020-02-17'::date)- interval 'day 91') 
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044 ) + 
    (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008  
    AND t.movementtype IN('I-','C-','M-','P-','V-','W-') 
    AND t.movementdate<('2020-02-17'::date) 
    AND t.rg_ID  = 1000044)) AS qty2,

    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.movementqty),0) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementdate > (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 181') 
    AND t.movementdate <= (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 270')
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000002
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+')) AS stock3,  ----stock 
    exist from previous brackets

    (SELECT (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449  
     AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+') 
    AND t.movementdate<(('2020-02-17'::date)- interval 'day 181') 
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044) + 
    (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
     t.M_Product_ID=1013449 
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008  
    AND t.movementtype IN('I-','C-','M-','P-','V-','W-') 
    AND t.movementdate<('2020-02-17'::date) 
    AND t.rg_ID  = 1000044)) AS qty3,

    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.movementqty),0) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementdate > (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 271') AND 
     t.movementdate > (('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 365')
     AND t.rg_ID  =1000044
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+')) AS stock4, 

    (SELECT (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449  
    AND t.Customer_ID=1000008 
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+') 
    AND t.movementdate<(('2020-02-17'::date)- interval 'day 271') 
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044 ) + 
    (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008  
    AND t.movementtype IN('I-','C-','M-','P-','V-','W-') 
    AND t.movementdate<('2020-02-17'::date) 
    AND t.rg_ID  = 1000002)) AS qty4,       -----no previous stock in previous 
    brackets

    (SELECT (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449  
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008 
    AND t.movementtype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+') 
    AND t.movementdate<(('2020-02-17'::date)-interval 'day 366') 
    AND t.rg_ID  =1000044 ) + 
    (SELECT SUM(t.movementqty) FROM M_merchandise t WHERE 
    t.M_Product_ID=1013449 
    AND t.Customer_ID =1000008  
    AND t.movementtype IN('I-','C-','M-','P-','V-','W-') 
    AND t.movementdate<('2020-02-17'::date) 
    AND t.rg_ID  = 1000044 ) ) AS qty5,   


    (SELECT COALESCE((cos.NewCostPrice),0) 
    FROM  history cos 
    LEFT JOIN M_CostElement ce on ce.M_CostElement_UU='bf6ee9b8-4600-480b- 
    b415- 
    f94c698b0648'
    LEFT JOIN m_costdetail md ON md.m_costdetail_id=cos.m_costdetail_id
    WHERE prod.M_Product_ID = md.M_Product_ID AND prod.ProductType !='A'
    AND cos.Customer_ID =1000008 AND md.Schema_ID = 1000004 
    AND cos.created >= (('2020-02-17'::date) - interval '3 month' ) 
    AND cos.created < ('2020-02-17'::date)
    AND cos.M_CostElement_ID=ce.M_CostElement_ID
    AND cos.rg_ID  = CASE WHEN cos.rg_ID  =0 Then cos.rg_ID  ELSE  
    1000002  END 
    ORDER BY cos.created DESC limit 1
    )as Cost1,

    (SELECT COALESCE((cos.NewCostPrice),0) 
    FROM  history cos 
    LEFT JOIN M_CostElement ce on ce.M_CostElement_UU='bf6ee9b8-4600-480b- 
   b415- 
    f94c698b0648'
    LEFT JOIN m_costdetail md ON md.m_costdetail_id=cos.m_costdetail_id
    WHERE prod.M_Product_ID = md.M_Product_ID AND prod.ProductType !='A'
    AND cos.Customer_ID =1000008 AND md.Schema_ID= 1000004 
    AND cos.created < (('2020-02-17'::date) - interval '3 month') 
    AND cos.created < (('2020-02-17'::date) - interval '6 month')
    AND cos.M_CostElement_ID=ce.M_CostElement_ID
    AND cos.rg_ID  = CASE WHEN cos.rg_ID  =0 Then cos.rg_ID  ELSE  
    1000002  END 
    ORDER BY cos.created DESC limit 1
    )as Cost2,

    (SELECT COALESCE((cos.NewCostPrice),0) 
    FROM  history cos 
    LEFT JOIN M_CostElement ce on ce.M_CostElement_UU='bf6ee9b8-4600-480b- 
    b415- 
    f94c698b0648'
    LEFT JOIN m_costdetail md ON md.m_costdetail_id=cos.m_costdetail_id
    WHERE prod.M_Product_ID = md.M_Product_ID AND prod.ProductType !='A'
    AND cos.Customer_ID =1000008 AND md.Schema_ID = 1000004 
    AND cos.created >= (('2020-02-17'::date) - interval '12 month' ) 
    AND cos.created < (('2020-02-17'::date) - interval '6 month')
    AND cos.M_CostElement_ID=ce.M_CostElement_ID
    AND cos.rg_ID = CASE WHEN cos.rg_ID =0 Then cos.rg_ID ELSE  
     1000002  END 
    ORDER BY cos.created DESC limit 1
    )as Cost3,

    (SELECT COALESCE((cos.NewCostPrice),0) 
    FROM  history cos 
    LEFT JOIN M_CostElement ce on ce.M_CostElement_UU='bf6ee9b8-4600-480b-b415- 
     f94c698b0648'
    LEFT JOIN m_costdetail md ON md.m_costdetail_id=cos.m_costdetail_id
    WHERE prod.M_Product_ID = md.M_Product_ID AND prod.ProductType !='A'
    AND cos.Customer_ID =1000008 AND md.Schema_ID = 1000004 
    AND cos.created < (('2020-02-17'::date)- interval '12 month')  
    AND cos.M_CostElement_ID=ce.M_CostElement_ID
    AND cos.rg_ID  = CASE WHEN cos.rg_ID  =0 Then cos.rg_ID  ELSE 
    1000002  END 
    ORDER BY cos.created DESC limit 1
     ) as Cost4,

    (SELECT COALESCE (SUM (st.qtyonhand),0)FROM M_Storage st
    WHERE prod.M_Product_ID = st.M_Product_ID 
    AND st.rg_ID  = 1000044  AND prod.ProductType !='A'
    AND  st.DateMaterialPolicy <= ( '2020-02-17'::date) 
    ) as OnHand 

    (SELECT COALESCE((cos.NewCostPrice),0) 
    FROM  m_costhistory cos 
    LEFT JOIN CostElem ce on ce.M_CostElem_UU='bf6ee9b8-4600-480b-b415- 
    f94c698b0648'
    LEFT JOIN costd md ON md.m_costd_id=cos.m_c
```

Comment: For optimisation questions, best to provide schema and explain analyse output, at least.

Comment: `Im looking for a way to reduce subqueries.` Why? There is nothing wrong with subqueries. you must stem from a mysql background.

Comment: Sorry, but your query looks broken.

Comment: @wildplasser Subqueries that are *not* in the `FROM` clause often cause performance problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i have edited the question and put the complete query, any suggestion would be appreciated .thank you

Comment: I would like to be able to do this using a procedure, im looking for guidance how i would implement that

Answer (score 0):

You excerpt does not look syntactically valid to me.  Please show it in a larger context.

Generally you can take the common conditions and put them in the WHERE clause of the query itself, and take the peculiar conditions and put them in WHERE clause of a FILTER.

So you could have something like this:

```
select 
  SUM(t.merchandiseqty) FILTER 
    (where t.merchandisetype IN('I+','M+','P+','V+','W+') AND t.merchandisedate<('2020-02-17'::date- interval 'day 271')) as whatever1,
  SUM(t.merchandiseqty) FILTER 
    (where t.merchandisetype IN ('I-','C-','M-','P-','V-','W-') AND t.merchandisedate<('2020-02-17'::date)) as qty1
FROM t WHERE t.M_merchandise_ID=1013449 AND t.customer_ID =1000008
```

Since your example was incomplete, I had to fill in the gaps with intuition.

It might also be helpful to move the least restrictive of the merchandisedate conditions out of the FILTER and into the main WHERE.

Comment: Hi jjanes thankx for quick response, So is FILTER like a prostgresql Funtion used like a where clause?

Comment: FILTER is an element of the SQL syntax, like SELECT or WHERE or FROM (but it applies only to aggregates).  It does not correspond to anything simple like a user-defined-function.